Ktor Google OAuth API Testing
I've been developing backend service using Ktor and regularly testing the running service with Insomnia. I began implementing OAuth 2.0 using Google OAuth and I have the flow working as expected within a web browser. However, when I attempt to test OAuth endpoints using Insomnia, I encounter an error page from Google like:


That’s an error.

The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know.

This happens after entering my email address and continuing within the Preview pane.
Code and setup instructions for reproduction found at this repository.
The OAuth configuration for the project is as follows:
internal fun Application.setupAuthorization(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    install(Sessions) { cookie<UserSession>("user_session") }

    val redirects = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    install(Authentication) {
        oauth("auth-oauth-google") {
            // Configure oauth authentication
            urlProvider = { "http://localhost:8080/callback" }
            providerLookup = {
                OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
                    name = "google",
                    authorizeUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                    accessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                    requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                    clientId = System.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
                    clientSecret = System.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                    defaultScopes = listOf("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"),
                    extraAuthParameters = listOf("access_type" to "offline"),
                    onStateCreated = { call, state ->
                        // saves new state with redirect url value
                        call.request.queryParameters["redirectUrl"]?.let {
                            redirects[state] = it
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            client = httpClient
        }
    }
    routing {
        authroute(httpClient, redirects)
        get("/logout") {
            call.sessions.clear<UserSession>()
            call.respondRedirect("/")
        }
    }
}

I've also configured Auth at the collection level in Insomnia by mirroring my settings from code. After enabling collection-level auth, I get the same experience as in the web via a pop-up window and can see via the console that I am receiving a Bearer token. But the endpoint request still presents the sign in page and gives the same error whether I manually add the Authorization header or not.
In either case, I'm expecting to be redirected to "/home" or "/profile", depending on the origin request, and given some basic details about my session. Ktor emits no logs after the initial 302 sending me to the login page.

So is the problem that you can see the State, Token, and ID in the server response but can't use the token with Insomnia to make a request to the protected resource?
